# empty a <div> when a <textarea> is empty

Tags: jquery

Im trying to clear the div .textoverlay if the textarea #IVRSendSMSBodyTextArea is empty, any ideas what im doing wrong?

```
if(pageData.IVRSendSMSBodyTextAreaVal)
{
    $('#IVRSendSMSBodyTextArea').removeAttr('placeholder').val(pageData.IVRSendSMSBodyTextAreaVal);
}
else{
    $('.textoverlay').empty();
    $('#IVRSendSMSBodyTextArea').val('');
}
```

**Output html:**

```
<li class="IVRSendSMSBodyTextArea">
<label for="IVRSendSMSBodyTextArea">Body:</label>
<div class="textoverlay-wrapper">
<div class="textoverlay" >dada <span style="background-color:#DDFFD1">@iInstrinsic1</span> 
</div>
<textarea id="IVRSendSMSBodyTextArea" cols="54" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
</li>
```

thanks

Comment: Seems fine. Btw. no need to remove the placeholder as it disappears automatically as soon as the value is not an empty string.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, or knowing what's in `pageData.IVRSendSMSBodyTextAreaVal`? Nope.

Comment: Works fine, as far as it goes: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/ytHGx

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#IVRSendSMSBodyTextArea').val()
```

will get you the actual textarea value, so

```
    if ( $('#IVRSendSMSBodyTextArea').val() === '' ){
 $('.textoverlay').html(''); // or $('.textoverlay').empty depends what you want to do }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$("#IVRSendSMSBodyTextArea").on('keyup',function(){
     $('.textoverlay').text(this.value);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fine. Try $('.textoverlay').html(''); as well.